# jQuery - Click one div, close all others issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a set of divs that when I click on one, it should open that particular one and close all others that are open. Should only be one open div if any. Having difficulty excluding the one I click from closing. Anyone have any thoughts? Javascript and HTML to follow:

```
    $('.m_box').hide();
    $('.a_box').hide();

    $('#m2012').click(function(){
        //$('.m_box').hide();
        $('#m2012_box').toggle();
    });

    $('#m2011').click(function(){
        //$('.m_box').hide();
        $('#m2011_box').toggle();
    });

    $('#m2010').click(function(){
        //$('.m_box').hide();
        $('#m2010_box').toggle();
    });

    <div id="m2012" style="float:left; margin:0 69px 0 0; width:15px; height:19px; cursor:pointer;">
        <div id="m2012_box" class="m_box" style="float:left; display:block; position:absolute; width:308px; height:351px; top:20px; margin-left:-37px; color:#ffffff; background:url('images/graph/list_background_left.png'); z-index:2000;">
            <div class="list_header">
                <p>2012</p>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 1
                </div>
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 2
                </div>
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 3
                </div>
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 4
                </div>
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 5
                </div>
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 6
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="m2011" style="float:left; margin:0 69px 0 0; width:15px; height:19px; cursor:pointer;">
        <div id="m2011_box" class="m_box" style="float:left; display:block; position:absolute; width:308px; height:351px; top:20px; margin-left:-37px; color:#ffffff; background:url('images/graph/list_background_left.png'); z-index:2000;">
            <div class="list_header">
                <p>2011</p>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 1
                </div>
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 2
                </div>
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="m2010" style="float:left; margin:0 69px 0 0; width:15px; height:19px; cursor:pointer;">
        <div id="m2010_box" class="m_box" style="float:left; display:block; position:absolute; width:308px; height:351px; top:20px; margin-left:-37px; color:#ffffff; background:url('images/graph/list_background_left.png'); z-index:2000;">
            <div class="list_header">
                <p>2010</p>
            </div>
            <div class="items">
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 1
                </div>
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 2
                </div>
                <div class="list_item">
                    Milestone 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude clicked div's child (the only as I see) from selector you can use `not`:

```
$('#m2012, #m2011, #m2010').click(function() {
    $('.m_box').not($(this).children().show()).hide();
});
```

UPD: modified the code so it opens the child.

Comment: This did it! along with:

$('#name_of_div').toggle();

Exclusion of the clicked div and then toggling said div is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: When it was accepted this answer doesn't work. @DaveRottino Why not check out the highest voted answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('.list_header').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('.items').hide();
    $(this).siblings().show();    
});​
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/J97Kq/

My fiddle removed your inline CSS for clarity purposes.

Comment: But this doesn't do what OP asked. He wants to close all sections when one is opened right?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the common class and the visible to select all and hide them first.

```
$('.m_box').click(function(){
    $('.m_box:visible').hide();
    $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two great pre-built jQuery libraries that can handle this:

- [jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/) (specifically the [tabs](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.html) functionality, which can be implemented as an [accordion](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/accordion.html))
- [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) which also has an [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) function

jQuery Tools will allow for the most flexibility, and implementing this should be relatively straightforward.  jQuery UI somewhat forces a certain styling, so Tools is probably the right approach if you want to use a library.

Comment: this doesn't look like an answer. post it as comments instead as an answer.

Comment: From "how to ask":
"The answer to your question may not always be the one you wanted, but that doesn’t mean it is wrong."

This is an answer to the question.  It solves the problem, even if it's not precisely what Dave was asking for.

Comment: Additionally, even if this wasn't precisely what he was asking for, this will likely be relevant to others who come upon this question via searching.

Answer (score -1):

You can close the other divs checking if they are opened with the :visible selector http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score -1):

You can try using jQuery to fadeIn and fadeOut the divs, on click event. Here is an example;

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

This means, when the div click me is clicked, it will fade out or fade in the book div

Answer (score -1):

you should use a selector to close all the div with a certain index like this, this selector close all divs with an index greater than 1.

```
 $('#m2012').click(function(){

 $('#m2012_box').toggle();

      //index a integer value

     $("div:gt(1)").hide();

});
```